# Python script skips certain lines when run without shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, stomp

I have some code like this:

```
from stomp import *
from stomp.listener import ConnectionListener
from stomp.utils import parse_frame

class MyListener(ConnectionListener):
  _counter=0
  def on_message(self, frame):
    if self._counter > 10:
      return
    print(self._counter)
    self._counter += 1

print('Starting...')
connection = Connection([('darwin-dist-44ae45.nationalrail.co.uk', '61613')])
connection.set_listener('', MyListener())
connection.connect(REDACTED)
connection.subscribe('/topic/darwin.pushport-v16', 11)
print('Ummm...???')
```

When I run this from command line using Python, the lines with `connection` don't execute:

```
$ python3 myscript.py                                                                                                                                       
Starting...
Ummm...???
```

However, when I open python shell and run these commands one by one, the `connection.subscribe('/topic/darwin.pushport-v16', 11)` produces a bunch of output as expected:

```
$ python3
>>> from stomp import *
>>> from stomp.listener import ConnectionListener
>>> from stomp.utils import parse_frame
>>> 
>>> class MyListener(ConnectionListener):
...   _counter=0
...   def on_message(self, frame):
...     if self._counter > 10:
...       return
...     print(self._counter)
...     self._counter += 1
... 
>>> print('Starting...')
Starting...
>>> connection = Connection([('darwin-dist-44ae45.nationalrail.co.uk', '61613')])
>>> connection.set_listener('', MyListener())
>>> connection.connect(REDACTED)
>>> connection.subscribe('/topic/darwin.pushport-v16', 11)
0
1
2
```

I have never encountered odd behavior like this before. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?
thanks

Comment: How do you know they're not running? They don't print anything by themselves.

Comment: I'm sure those lines are running, it must not be receiving any messages so there's nothing to print.

Comment: The `MyListener` instance passed in does the printing. As mentioned in the question, there are messages and they are indeed printed when I run using the shell. Please see accepted answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that nothing is keeping your application from exiting. Therefore, it has no time to actually receive any messages. However, when you run it from the Python shell it has time to receive messages and print the counter.

Try something like this:

```py
import time
from stomp import *
from stomp.listener import ConnectionListener
from stomp.utils import parse_frame

class MyListener(ConnectionListener):
  _counter=0
  def on_message(self, frame):
    if self._counter > 10:
      return
    print(self._counter)
    self._counter += 1

print('Starting...')
connection = Connection([('darwin-dist-44ae45.nationalrail.co.uk', '61613')])
connection.set_listener('', MyListener())
connection.connect(REDACTED)
connection.subscribe('/topic/darwin.pushport-v16', 11)
print('Ummm...???')
time.sleep(30)
connection.disconnect()
```

It's important to keep in mind that the `MyListener` instance set on `connection` when invoking `set_listener` will be invoked **asynchronously** when a message arrives on the queue. In other words, the client won't simply wait/block until a message arrives. Therefore, *something* needs to keep the consumer alive for a bit waiting for a message. If a message arrives during this 30 second sleep then the `MyListener` will receive it and print the counter. If a message doesn't arrive on the queue then the `MyListener` won't be invoked and the application will simply terminate.